# React `or` condition in className `if` statement

Tags: css, reactjs, conditional-operator

I have a React application and want to change a CSS class when one condition is met or another. How do I do this?

So, if `validation` or `validationNoExist` is `false` then the CSS class should be `input-form-validation-wrong`, if both are correct then the first class is selected.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="email"  className={validation || validationNoExist ? 'input-form' : 'input-form-validation-wrong'} placeholder="E-Mail" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may just be an issue of grouping the logical operator so they are evaluated as a unit for the condition test for the ternary. They both need to be true for the ternary to return "input-form".

```
<input
  type="email"
  className={(validation && validationNoExist) ? 'input-form' : 'input-form-validation-wrong'}
  placeholder="E-Mail"
/>
```

```js
console.log((false && false) ? 'input-form' : 'input-form-validation-wrong');
console.log((true && false) ? 'input-form' : 'input-form-validation-wrong');
console.log((false && true) ? 'input-form' : 'input-form-validation-wrong');
console.log((true && true) ? 'input-form' : 'input-form-validation-wrong');
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
<input type="email"  className={(validation || validationNoExist) ? 'input-form' : 'input-form-validation-wrong'} placeholder="E-Mail" />
```